# Is it possible that codeigniter prevents fetching data from some tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to codeigniter and I'm faced with a challenge.
I'm working on an ecommerce project which had pre-built tables in the database it came with. I then changed the theme of the code and I'm incorporating an MLM Unilevel system to it. when I fetch data, everything works fine.

Now the problem arose when I created a new table "members" and I'm trying to fetch records from it. I used this line `$query = $this->db->get('members');`, but it returns blank page when I try to query all records from the members table. When I change the table name to "users" `$query = $this->db->get('users');`, it returns the records of the users table, without any other change in code.

I then quickly opened a raw codeigniter project which I use for learning and inserted the code to it and tested both `$query = $this->db->get('members');` and `$query = $this->db->get('users');`, everything seems to be working just fine.

Is it possible could be a script in parts of the codes of the head tag preventing the fetching of data from the members table while at the same time doing the opposite in users table? Or is there a way codeigniter defines the tables that would be used by the app while preventing other tables created which are not in that list to fetch data from? I even tried deleting the contents of the HEAD (App), but still no solution to the problem. I have tried searching for possible solutions but I don't seem to get any that addresses this.

Here is my code.

MODEL:

```
class Action_model extends CI_Model{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}
public function select_all_data(){
    //select all data from table
    $query = $this->db->get('members');
    return $result = $query->result();
} 
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class Action extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('action_model');
}
public function get_all_data()
{
    $data = $this->action_model->select_all_data();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
}
}
```

HEAD (App): (tested with this head in my app and members table returns a blank page)

```
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo isset($meta_desc) ? $meta_desc : META_DESC; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo isset($meta_keys) ? $meta_keys : META_KEYWORDS; ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<title><?php echo isset($page_title) ? $page_title : SITE_TITLE; ?></title>
<!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url('favicon.png'); ?>"/>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url('favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Custom Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/authentication.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/color_skins.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/tree.css'); ?>">   
<!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Css -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Wait Me Css -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/waitme/waitMe.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Bootstrap Select Css -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- JQuery DataTable Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'); ?>">
```

HEAD (Test): (tested with this head and both tables return results)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php if (!empty($title)) echo $title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" />
```

RETURNED RESULTS:

MEMBERS: (visible in Test, but not in main App project)

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [member_id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [referral_key] => 12345
        [up_line] => 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1
        [status] => Active
        [token] => 1-123456789
        [created_on] => 2020-12-07 07:23:07
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [member_id] => 20
        [user_id] => 2
        [referral_key] => 44231
        [up_line] => 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1
        [status] => Active
        [token] => 2-799148954
        [created_on] => 2020-12-07 15:29:05
    )
)
```

USERS: (Visible in both projects)

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [country_id] => 197
        [user_type] => admin
        [referral_id] => 1
        [sponsor_id] => 
        [first_name] => Don
        [last_name] => Don
        [display_name] => 
        [dob] => 0000-00-00
        [gender] => Male
        [id_number] => 105135049
        [email] => don***@gmail.com
        [password] => 67d************************7df
        [reset_code] => 
        [phone] => 07***7
        [city] => Johannesburg
        [avatar] => 
        [profile_desc] => Test start
        [token] => dfuiefeufieyfrjidyf8ug78f7r784
        [is_member] => Yes
        [blocked] => 0
        [joined] => 2020-12-04 19:23:30
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => 2
        [country_id] => 225
        [user_type] => member
        [referral_id] => 2
        [sponsor_id] => 1
        [first_name] => Sam
        [last_name] => Peter
        [display_name] => 
        [dob] => 0000-00-00
        [gender] => Male
        [id_number] => 
        [email] => sa***@gmail.com
        [password] => 322************************a24
        [reset_code] => 
        [phone] => +44***9
        [city] => London
        [avatar] => 
        [profile_desc] => Some content about myself.
        [token] => mn84u89gh4iuyg849yfuy48j9r4
        [is_member] => Yes
        [blocked] => 0
        [joined] => 2020-12-05 17:00:41
    )
)
```

I appreciate any support that resolves this issue for me.

Thanks.

DB CONFIGURATION

```
$active_group = 'default'; 
$active_record = TRUE;  
$db['default'] = array(     
    'dsn'   => '',     
    'hostname' => 'localhost',     
    'username' => 'root',     
    'password' => 'rootpass',     
    'database' => 'e_mhearnings',     
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',     
    'dbprefix' => '',     
    'pconnect' => FALSE,     
    'db_debug' => TRUE,     
    'cache_on' => FALSE,     
    'cachedir' => '',     
    'char_set' => 'utf8',     
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',     
    'swap_pre' => '',     
    'encrypt' => FALSE,     
    'compress' => FALSE,     
    'stricton' => FALSE,     
    'failover' => array(),     
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log file for message?

Comment: Hi @SamuelAsor, I have been scratching my head around where is the log file in Xampp on windows. tried the query in my db, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_file%'`, which returns the name "slow_query_log_file: ucode-slow.log". I've been scavenging my system, but don't seem to find where the file is located.

Comment: Been doing some more digging, just saw the mysql_error.log file in Xampp/mysql/data. What specifically would I be looking for in there? I don't understand, nor have I worked with the xampp log file before.

Comment: CodeIgniter has it's own error logging mechanism, and you can find your error logs in the  `application/logs/` folder.

Comment: So I found the log folder, turned on error logging to 1 in the config/config.php file and I'm able to see log messages coming in. I optionally changed members to member and got an error message: `Query error: Table 'e_mhe.member' doesn't exist` and a visible error on the screen, but when I reverse it to members table, it gives me a blank page, and no error in the log file.

Comment: Wow, this really is weird. Can you paste in your question the config values you have in your `application/config/database.php` file ?

Comment: Comment too long, stackoverflow is asking that I start a chat.

Comment: I don't see this `$query_builder = TRUE;` in your code. Is that intentional?